# concatenate activerecord relations using "or" condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two queries

```
urgent = MassScanTask.joins(:mass_scan_list).where("mass_scan_lists.urgent = ? AND mass_scan_lists.enabled = ?", true, true).order("updated_at DESC")
not_urgent = MassScanTask.joins(:mass_scan_list).where("mass_scan_lists.urgent = ? AND mass_scan_lists.enabled = ? ", false, true).order("updated_at ASC")
```

how can I get them all together `urgent + not_urgent` using single query? Or maybe there is some method to add one to another. I have already tried `concat` but it returns array and I need activerecord relations, I have also tried `merge` but it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, looking at these queries, it seems that you want all `enabled` rows from the `mass_scan_lists` table, but the only difference is the ordering. You want all `urgent to come first, ordered by`updated_at desc`and then have`non-urgent`ordered by`updated_at`.

So, I would just use some custom SQL in the `order` statement. You don't specify what RDBMS you are using, but if it is PostgreSQL, it would look like:

`tasks = MassScanTask \
  .joins(:mass_scan_list) \
  .where(mass_scan_lists: { enabled: true }) \
  .order('case urgent when true then -1 * extract(epoch from updated_at) else extract(epoch from updated_at) end')`

This order clause uses a [CASE statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-conditional.html), which is not supported in all DBs, but whatever you are using likely has a similar clause.